# How to fix function "SetRebarColumn " to insert parameters from excel to etabs correctly?

Tags: excel, vba

I have used "SetRebarColumn" (related to ETABSV17 object library) in excel vba to insert parameters like "rebar property & cover" to etabs but it does'nt.what's the problem in the code?

```
Sub AssignColumnRebar()

   'dimension variables

      Dim EtabsObject as cOAPI
      Dim SapModel As cSapModel
      Dim ret As integer


   'create ETABS object

      Set EtabsObject = CreateObject("CSI.ETABS.API.ETABSObject")

      'start ETABS application

      EtabsObject .ApplicationStart

     'create SapModel object

      Set SapModel = EtabsObject .SapModel

   'initialize model

      ret = SapModel.InitializeNewModel

   'create model from template

      ret = SapModel.File.New2DFrame(2, 2, 144, 2, 288)

   'set new frame section property

      ret = SapModel.PropFrame.SetRectangle("R1", "4000Psi", 30, 30)

   'set column rebar data

      ret = SapModel.PropFrame.SetRebarColumn("R1", "A615Gr60", "A416Gr270", 1, 1, 2, 10, 0, 0, "#10", "#5", 4, 0, 0, False)

      Set SapModel = Nothing
      Set EtabsObject = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the materials 4000 Psi , A615Gr60, and A416Gr270  are not yet defined in you model.

Comment: These materials are defined as default in section of material property in ETABS.

Comment: I guess the function doesn't work properly.I used "SetRebarBeam" that worked well but "SetRebarColumn" couldn't handle.